# Redundance Conformance of User to Protocol PFSubclassing (Swift 2.0)

Tags: ios, parse-platform, swift2, pfuser, pfsubclassing

[image]

I just migrated my Swift 1.2 code to Swift 2.0.

This code previously works fine. but now there is an error saying

```
Redundance Conformance of User to Protocol PFSubclassing (Swift 2.0)
```

What might be causing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PFUser Conforms PFSubclassing Protocol. So no need to Conform PFSubclassing in you subclass.
Remove PFSubclassing will work.

**class LCUser : PFUSer {

// data members
}**